# How can you use the potential to find the electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

[image: ![enter image description here]

Lets say we have the above system of point charges.

We were asked to find the electric field at the centre. Superposition of electric fields gives the right answer, but how can we do it by considering potentials?

I know $- dV/dx= E$, so I found the potential at the centre to be $2Q/4\pi \epsilon_0 a$, but just differentiating this wrt a gives me E = $2Q/4 \pi \epsilon_0 a^2$.

I am missing a factor of $\sqrt3$.

I am guessing this is because I am not considering the appropriate directions. But how do i do this?

EDIT:

My working:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if those charges on top are negative or not. Calculating the electric field by taking the potential derivative should give you the correct answer if you remember the following:

- The electric fieldis a vector so $E_x = -\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}}$ and $E_y = -\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{y}}$ and $E=\sqrt{E_x^2+E_y^2}$
- The potential of the system is the sum of the potential of each charge. The potential of each charge must account for it's displacement from the origin. That is, $ V = \frac{kq}{\sqrt{(x+a/2)^2+(y+a/2)^2}} + \frac{kq}{\sqrt{(x-a/2)^2+(y+a/2)^2}} + ...$

Comment: The top two charges are negative Q

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about more than just one point. Since your problem is symmetric, you can work in 1D. Find the potential as a function $V(x)$ along the vertical line passing through the center between the $-Q$ charges. Then take the derivative of that function.

Comment: Ive tried that, but I seem to be off by a factor of 2, can you show me your working?

Comment: @Vishal Jain Please edit your first post, and show what you attempted.

Comment: I have now done so. Can you please see what I have done wrong. Thank you,

Comment: You haven't shown your work that implements the procedure suggested by @HiddenBabel

Comment: @VishalJain For example, the potential from each of the negative charges will be $$\frac{-kQ}{\sqrt{(a/2)^2 + (\sqrt{3}a/2 - y)^2}}$$ but it will be different for the other charges.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field isn't the derivative of the potential, it's the gradient of the potential. Yes, the gradient is the three dimensional version of the derivative, but I don't see that you are clearly treating this as a three dimensional problem. You have $a$ as being two different line segments, and you also divide by it, which suggests that you are treating it as a magnitude, rather than a vector. You then take the partial derivative with respect to $y$. What's $y$? And then you have $a^y$. Is that supposed to be $a_y$?  You need to express the potential as function with three arguments and take the gradient of that. This will then be a vector, not a scalar. To top it off, you say you're taking the derivative with respect to $a$, but $a$ appears to be a parameter, not a variable.

That is, find $V(x,y,z)$, then find $E =- \left(\frac {\delta V}{\delta x}, \frac {\delta V}{\delta y}, \frac {\delta V}{\delta z} \right)$. $E$ is then the electric field in tems of $x,y,z$. If you want the strength of the electric field, you take $|E|$. That's probably where the $\sqrt 3$ comes in: you seem to have calculated only one component of $E$.

Comment: I understand what youre saying but I cant seem to do it. I thought I was taking into account the different dimensions by considering ax and ay.  Are you saying to find the potential at a general distance x away, then differentiate that and plug x = $(\sqrt 3 / 2) a$?

Comment: @VishalJain No, I'm saying find V in terms of x,y, and z, then take the gradient. See my edit.